# Ошибка при вводе значения в переменную "Access violation at addres"

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм

В case 3 на вводе xedit выдаёт ошибку

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma argsused

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <stdio.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <conio.h>

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

struct TZap {
    char FIO[30];
    int god_r;
    int n_gr;
    int ocen_fiz, ocen_mat, ocen_inf, ocen_him;
    double s_b;
}
Zap;
int size = sizeof( TZap );
FILE *Fz, *Ft;
char File_Zap[] = "zapisi.dat";
char File_Rez[] = "rezult.txt";
void Out( TZap );

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    int kod, D_f, i = 0, j, kol, x = -1;
    char afio[30];
    int agod_r, an_gr, aocen_fiz, aocen_mat, aocen_inf, aocen_him, as_b;
    int xedit = 0;
    long len;
    TZap st, *mas_Z;
    Ft = fopen( File_Rez, "w" );
    char fio_edit[30];

    while( true ) {
        puts( "\n\n 1 - Create\n 2 - Add\n 3 - Edit\n 4 - View\n\n 0 - Exit" );
        printf( "\n\t" );
        scanf( "%d", &kod );

        switch( kod ) {
            case 1:
                if( ( Fz = fopen( File_Zap, "wb" ) ) == NULL ) {
                    puts( "\n Create ERROR! Press any key!" );
                    getch();
                    continue;
                }

                fclose( Fz );
                printf( "\n Create New File %s !\n", File_Zap );
                break;

            case 2:
                Fz = fopen( File_Zap, "ab" );
                printf( "\n F.I.O. - " );
                fflush( stdin );
                printf( "\n\t" );
                gets( Zap.FIO );
                printf( " Year of birth - " );
                printf( "\n\t" );
                scanf( "%d", &Zap.god_r );
                printf( " Group number - " );
                printf( "\n\t" );
                scanf( "%d", &Zap.n_gr );
                printf( " Physics - " );
                printf( "\n\t" );
                scanf( "%d", &Zap.ocen_fiz );
                printf( " Mathematics - " );
                printf( "\n\t" );
                scanf( "%d", &Zap.ocen_mat );
                printf( " Computer science - " );
                printf( "\n\t" );
                scanf( "%d", &Zap.ocen_inf );
                printf( " Chemistry - " );
                printf( "\n\t" );
                scanf( "%d", &Zap.ocen_him );
                printf( " Mark - " );
                printf( "\n\t" );
                scanf( "%lf", &Zap.s_b );
                fwrite( &Zap, size, 1, Fz );
                fclose( Fz );
                break;

            case 3:
                if( ( Fz = fopen( File_Zap, "rb" ) ) == NULL ) {
                    puts( "\n Open ERROR! Press any key!" );
                    getch();
                    continue;
                }

                printf( "\n Vvedite F.I.O." );
                fflush( stdin );
                printf( "\n\t" );
                gets( fio_edit );
                Fz = fopen( File_Zap, "rb" );
                D_f = fileno( Fz );
                len = filelength( D_f );
                kol = len / size;
                mas_Z = new TZap[kol];

                for( i = 0; i < kol; i++ ) {
                    fread( ( mas_Z + i ), size, 1, Fz );
                }

                fclose( Fz );

                for( int i = 0; i < kol; ++i )
                    if( strcmp( mas_Z[i].FIO, fio_edit ) == 0 ) {
                        x = i;
                        break;
                    }
                    else {
                        x = -1;
                    }

                if( x == -1 ) {
                    puts( "\tSovpadenii net" );
                }
                else {
                    printf( " Edit:\n 1 - F.I.O\n 2 - Year of birth\n 3 - Group number\n 4 - Physics\n 5 - Mathematics\n 6 - Computer science\n 7 - Chemistry\n 8 - Mark\n" );
                    printf( "\n\t" );
                    scanf( "%d", &xedit );
                    printf( "%d", &xedit );
                    /* switch()
                     {
                             case 1:
                                     printf("Vvedite F.I.O.");
                                     //printf("\n\t");gets(afio);
                             break;
                             case 0:

                             return(0);
                     }*/
                }

                delete []mas_Z;
                break;

            case 4:
                if( ( Fz = fopen( File_Zap, "rb" ) ) == NULL ) {
                    puts( "\n Open ERROR! Press any key!" );
                    getch();
                    continue;
                }

                printf( "\n\t--------- Informations ---------\n" );
                fprintf( Ft, "\n\t--------- Informations ---------" );

                while( 1 ) {
                    if( !fread( &Zap, size, 1, Fz ) ) {
                        break;
                    }

                    Out( Zap );
                }

                fclose( Fz );
                break;

            case 0:
                fclose( Ft );
                return( 0 );
        }
    }

    return( 0 );
}

void Out( TZap z )
{
    printf( "\n %20s, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %1f\n\n\t", z.FIO, z.god_r, z.n_gr,
            z.ocen_fiz, z.ocen_mat, z.ocen_inf, z.god_r, z.s_b );
    fprintf( Ft, "\n %20s, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %1f\n\n\t", z.FIO, z.god_r,
             z.n_gr, z.ocen_fiz, z.ocen_mat, z.ocen_inf, z.god_r, z.s_b );
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка "Access violation ..." может говорить о том, что где-то до её появления вы "запарываете" память. В коде `case 3` сразу бросаются в глаза следующие вещи:

1. Двойное открытие файла `File_Zap` на чтение
2. Вызов небезопасной функции `gets()`
3. Отсутствие проверок возврата `fread()`

Общий путь для поиска подобных ошибок: сначала загрузить программу в отладчике, пройтись по шагам, и внимательно посмотреть своими глазами на состояние переменных, что куда пишется, не происходит ли переполнение буферов, порча предыдуще заданных значений и т.д. Если по каким-то причинам это не поможет, то можно воспользоваться утилитами для поиска ошибок работы с памятью. Судя по всему, речь о Windows, поэтому - [Valgrind for Windows](https://sourceforge.net/p/valgrind4win/wiki/Home/) и большой список других - [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413477/).

Comment: 1 и 2 пункты результата не дали

Comment: То есть вы 1) не нашли ничего подозрительного под отладчиком и 2) ни одна из десятка утилит не показала никаких ошибок?

Comment: Это разве 1 и 2? Я закрыл File_Zap и поменял функцию на scanf

Comment: Да, это первый и второй пункты в пути поиска подобных ошибок.

Comment: Ваш ответ не решает проблему.

Comment: @Евгений, а вы что, действительно думаете что тут все всё бросят и начнут отлаживать ваш код за вас? Пути поиска ошибки я указал, дальше самостоятельно. Тем более что все данные, с которыми работает программа - у вас.

Comment: http://xxo.su/resizer/i/5/d/797b9b79.png Не падает же?

Comment: не понимаю о_О Возможно проблема в среде?

Comment: Проблема может быть где угодно, в том числе и провоцироваться конкретным набором данных. Поэтому - отладчик в руки и смотреть своими глазами, в тех условиях, в которых глюк проявляется, а не тратить время на угадайку вслепую.

Comment: Дело в том что надо было записывать в переменную через & а вывод без