# анализаторы утечки памяти С/С++

Tags: c++, c, память, утечка-памяти

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, толковый анализатор утечки памяти. Не могу разобраться, на что уходит память. В процессах видно, как объём используемой программой памяти постоянно растёт. Но у меня не используется динамическое выделение памяти, только заранее определённые переменные и массивы определённого размера.

В цикле вызываются функции `send`/`recv` и `libssh2_channel_write`/`libssh2_channel_read`, работающие с одним и тем же буфером. Цикл же работает в отдельном потоке, созданном с `CreateThread`. Но он один.

Программа под **Windows**, собирается в MinGW.

Answer (score 0):

Утечку нашёл в самописной usleep использующей select. Забыл сокет закрыть.

Но вопрос, остаётся открытым.
Существует ли что-либо подобное Valgrind но под Windows (для не внимательных).

Спасибо!

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/575994/194908